# How to display only one infowindow at a time in google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can we display only one infowindow at a time in google map with multiple infowindows for multiple markers.

Means , hide/close other infowindows when i click on a marker & display only current marker infowindow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript code i have used when displaying single marker at a time.

After a search of almost 3 hours i figured it out and in a simple way if you add multiple markers in this way

```js
var markerArray=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            {
                var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].Latitude, markers[i].Longitude),
                    title: markers[i].Name + ", "+ markers[i].Address,
                    draggable: false
                });

                var statusStr;
                //Set marker icon depending upon current stage
                switch (markers[i].Stage)
                {
                    //Stage 1 - Brochure
                    case 5: newMarker.setIcon(stage1MarkerImage);
                        statusStr = 'Current Status - <select id="status"> <option id="5" value="Brochure" selected="selected">Brochure</option><option id="6" value="Demo">Demo</option><option id="7" value="Site Visit">Site Visit</option><option id="8" value="Lease Approval">Lease Approval</option></select>';
                        break;
                        //Stage 2 - Demo
                    case 6: newMarker.setIcon(stage2MarkerImage);
                        statusStr = 'Current Status - <select id="status"> <option id="5" value="Brochure" >Brochure</option><option id="6" value="Demo" selected="selected">Demo</option><option id="7" value="Site Visit">Site Visit</option><option id="8" value="Lease Approval">Lease Approval</option></select>';
                        break;
                        //Stage 3 - Site Visit
                    case 7: newMarker.setIcon(stage3MarkerImage);
                        statusStr = 'Current Status - <select id="status"> <option id="5" value="Brochure" >Brochure</option><option id="6" value="Demo" >Demo</option><option id="7" value="Site Visit" selected="selected">Site Visit</option><option id="8" value="Lease Approval">Lease Approval</option></select>';
                        break;
                        //Stage 4 - Lease Approval
                    case 8: newMarker.setIcon(stage4MarkerImage);
                        statusStr = 'Current Status - <select id="status"> <option id="5" value="Brochure" >Brochure</option><option id="6" value="Demo" >Demo</option><option id="7" value="Site Visit" ><Site Visit/option><option id="8" value="Lease Approval" selected="selected">Lease Approval</option></select>';
                        break;
                }



                newMarker["infoWindow"] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:
                 '<div class="infoWindow">' +
                '<header>' + markers[i].Name + '</header>' +
                '<div style="clear: both;"></div>' +
                '<div class="content">' +
                '<p>' + markers[i].Address + ', ' + markers[i].City + ', ' + markers[i].State + ', ' + markers[i].CountryName + '</p>' +
                '<p>' +
                 statusStr+
                '<label id="update-status" onclick="updateCustomerStep(this);" data-id="' + markers[i].Id + '" >Update</label>' +
                '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function () {

                    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        var currentMarker = markerArray[i];
                        currentMarker["infoWindow"].close();
                        console.log(currentMarker);
                    }

                    this['infoWindow'].open(map, this);

                });

                markerArray.push(newMarker);
            }
```

Comment: Nooooooooo! If only one infoWindow will ever be open at a time, then create ONE infoWindow and change its content whenever it is opened.

Comment: what if you have create & open infowindow contents from database, say for multiple stores, how it will get its contents & what if i have to change marker icon from infowindow content button, will one infowindow work in this case. Can you please suggest updates in above code (working) to fit this solution.

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved it is as follow

```
var infoWindowsOpenCurrently;// A temporarily variable to save currently opened info window
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  typeof infoWindowsOpenCurrently !== 'undefined' && infoWindowsOpenCurrently.close();//if variable is defined close
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  infoWindowsOpenCurrently = infowindow;//set current info window to temporary variable
});
```

Comment: Just gotta say bless 

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your code for a bit and ended with this :

```
var markerArray = [];//necessary???

var infoHTML = '<div class="infoWindow"><header></header><div style="clear: both;"></div><div class="content"><p class="address"></p><p>Current Status - <select id="status"> <option value="5">Brochure</option><option value="6">Demo</option><option value="7">Site Visit</option><option value="8">Lease Approval</option></select><label>Update</label></p></div></div>';

//One infoWindow with dynamic content
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoHTML
});

$(infoWindow).find("label").on('click', function() {
    var stage = $(this).prev("select").val();
    var marker = $(this).data('marker')
    marker.data.Stage = stage;
    updateCustomerStep(marker, stage);
});

function openInfoWin() {
    var data = this.data;
    var $infoWindow = $(infoWindow);
    var $select = $infoWindow.find("select").val(data.Stage);
    $infoWindow.find("label").data('marker',this);
    $infoWindow.find("header").text(data.Name);
    $infoWindow.find(".address").text([data.Address, data.City, data.State, data.CountryName].join(', '));
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
}

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];

    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude),
        title: data.Name + ", " + data.Address,
        draggable: false
    });

    //Set marker icon depending upon current stage
    switch (data.Stage) {
        case 5: newMarker.setIcon(stage1MarkerImage); break;//Stage 1 - Brochure
        case 6: newMarker.setIcon(stage2MarkerImage); break;//Stage 2 - Demo
        case 7: newMarker.setIcon(stage3MarkerImage); break;//Stage 3 - Site Visit
        case 8: newMarker.setIcon(stage4MarkerImage); break;//Stage 4 - Lease Approval
    }

    newMarker.data = data;
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', openInfoWin);
    markerArray.push(newMarker);//necessary???
}
```

Notes:

- untested
- Status options now have a value equal to what was id.
- markerArray is no longer needed unless it is used elewhere in the code.
- the function `updateCustomerStep` will need to be modified to have formal variables (marker, stage).

Comment: Well, i will test this code & reply to you soon. But thanks for your time &  efforts.