# trigger google maps place infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried under code, it only invoke click event on map, but not open the infowindow like in picture, when mouse click it.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', latlng);
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDgQV.png)

Comment: check this question you may find something useful. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464037/how-to-display-only-one-infowindow-at-a-time-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: you should check out the map documentation. There is an example here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple - on infowindows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trigger the "place" InfoWindows (for the POIs shown on the Google Map tiles)

Comment: Thank me by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)